# How to get task hours in resources usage view in ms project by VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I want to get one of these values (108,10,21...) from resources usage and do some operations on it in VBA macro (for exemple add a number to it and put it in another cell ) but i don't know how , I tried to learn by record macro but it didn't work. I hope my question is clear if not just ask for clarify and I will do it .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is the work at the assignment level, by resource. For example:

```
Sub GetAssignmentWorkByResource()

    Dim r As Resource
    For Each r In ActiveProject.Resources
        Dim a As Assignment
        For Each a In r.Assignments
            Debug.Print r.Name, a.Task.Name, a.Work / 60 & " h"
        Next a
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

See [Resource object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource), [Assignment object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,  what I am trying to do is to get these numbers ( I tried task.GetTaskField() and GetTaskFieldID but none of them work ), And then do some operations about it for example i will get how much hours resource will work which is in this example 108 i will divide it by 8 it's13.5 and like that i will know that resource will work 14 days to complete his tasks each day 8h of work . any advice how to do it ? thanks again for the reply

Comment: the_yaz2000, if all you want to see is the resource work expressed in days, go to File > Options > Schedule group and change the "Work is entered in" to "Days"

Comment: @john-project not to expressed but to manage the resources works , for example (img in the question) the resource have 4 tasks , I will put in his first day 8h of task1 and day2 i will put 2h of task1 plus 6h of task4 so he can work 8h and so on.

Comment: @the_yaz2000 Sounds like you are looking to 'level the resource assignments', if so see [Distribute project work evenly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/distribute-project-work-evenly-level-resource-assignments-59ee715d-4446-42c9-8756-4ea2a5a7e4a0).

Comment: the_yaz2000 I don't understand what yo are trying to do with VBA. If you are trying to optimize resource usage (i.e insure each resource has a full 8h of task assignments each day), that will be a very complex macro. The resource leveling noted by Rachel will NOT optimize assignments, it will only attempt to resolve resource overallocation.

Comment: @john-project you right !! that what I am trying to do, I know it's hard but I took very good steps to it , the first step was to get all the information I need and Rachel help me with that by her macro.thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

A few additional comments about the code above after a few tests :

**1. Resource pool**

If you are using a resource pool, and you want to check the workload of a person, there's just one little correction to do on the code above :

**a.Task.Name** must be replaced by **a.TaskName**.

Both fields are available on a project or on the resource pool, but strangely a.Task.Name always comes out empty when you're on the pool.
a.TaskName is always filled. (with the same value, I verified)

**2. Workload on a specific project**

If you want to check the workload of resources on a specific project, just use the code above, but do not open your resource pool if you have one.

(If the resource pool is not open, MS project will review the assignments of the resources in the resource sheet of your project.
If the pool is open, MS project will review the assignments of the resources in the resource sheet of the pool.)

**3. Masterplan / Subprojects**

When you use a masterplan with only subprojects in it you must have your resource pool open.
Even though some resources appear on the resource sheet, MS project will not review them when the pool is not open.